# Is it safe to run 2 or more RStudio sessions simultaneously?

Tags: r, neural-networks

I am working on some neural networks' benchmarks and they take a significant amount of time to finish. So, I am using multiple RStudio sessions to run them simultaneously. Is this safe? I mean is it safe from the perspective of the variables, because I ran the same script with slightly changed the parameters of the neural networks. Are the variables being affected by these sessions? Do they overlap?

e.g. if I have a counter variable does it increase from both sessions?

Comment: do you really need the interface ? you can run in via Rscript ...

Comment: Its more convient to me. If there was a problem with the interface and teh shared memory I would try the Rscript. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open up your process explorer, do you see two copies of R studio (or R itself) running?  If so, than your operating system has allocated *separate* memory spaces for the two copies of R studio, in which case you are perfectly safe.

In general, you have to do lots of work to *share* memory, and most well written programs will do their best to protect you from the risks of doing so.

Comment: Yeap! You're right! I see two copies of R Studio running! So as you say it must be safe and no memory is shared between them.

Comment: @vagelis if you do so you waste lots of system resources for Rstudio GUI, better way to go would be to run multiple instances of R alone....

Comment: @Tim Yah, I'll second that, good point.

Comment: An appropriate place for such questions would be the forums the R Studio site hosts.